# Bug in woocommerce FROM email address field - address not being used

Tags: email, woocommerce

HELP! I can find no way to report a bug in woocommerce. The issue is that the emails being sent are coming from an address OTHER than the one specified in the "From" Address field. It's not even close. The specified email is me@mydomain.com and the new account email (for example) is showing as coming from sales@someotherdomain.us which is not entered in WordPress or WooCommerce anywhere. The only tie the two domains have is that they are both hosted on the same server.

How can I change the FROM address to my own? (the one entered in the "From" Address field?)

Answer (score 0):

There are two places you need to set the from address:

**Settings -> General -> Email Address**

and

**WooCommerce -> Settings -> Emails -> "From Address"**

If changing them both do not work, then you may need to install an SMTP plugin so that you have more control over the way WordPress sends e-mails. **WP Mail SMTP** before if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Those both show the correct address (hence my belief it's a bug). Tried the plugin and now I am getting no emails   :-(   I DID find that the email used before was set as the default email on the server and was used when the sender email was not specified (but, of course, it was specified in both placed it should have been) I made sure all the settings in the WP-Main-SMTP plugin were correct.

Comment: OK. So I deactivated those new mail plugins, and now the original email is working as it should be - I get emails from the correct domain and address. Go figure? The only reason I can come up with is that those plugins overwrote some setting, then set it back (correctly this time) where the original plugin did not. But, I don't think this solution would have presented itself if you had not suggested what you did, so a BIG THANK YOU to you, Kodaloid! Have any suggestions for how to make the logo larger on the Porto theme? I can only make it 25% of the width of the header. where is that value?

Comment: No problem, glad you managed to figure it out :) Although I have not worked with that specific theme, you should be able to resize the logo using CSS. If you are not using a child theme, then there are plugins that allow you to add your own custom CSS.

Comment: I have another wc question if you have a chance to look at it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016051/min-cart-issue-using-woocommerce-wordpress