# Min Cart issue using woocommerce + wordpress,

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Reference to woocommerce in wordpress, I've come across an annoying bug. In the MiniCart, it shows the number of items in the cart. This works fine until I use the + or - to change the quantity. If I do that, the number just becomes a spinning wheel and the cart icon no longer shows the cart items. Now, get this: IF I delete the last item in the cart, it shows the correct number of items and shows the cart contents again. Anyone have any ideas what could be causing that? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Caching is the issue here

Comment: I tried loading it on another PC that never visited the site and it shows the same thing. But, could you be more specific as to how to solve it if it is a caching issue? When you use the ADD TO CART button it works fine. When you change the quantity, it never refreshes. I tried loading another cart plugin that works fine, but it does not show the cart contents when you hover over the mini cart icon. I'm fairly certain it's an issue with wc or a plugin, and not with the local PC.

Comment: I disabled WP Super Cache and it solved the issue. Thanks for the reply. When you said cache, I was thinking local cache not site cache.

Answer (score 0):

Possible thing that may reason for this:

- Ajax related issue
  This cause due to jquery version mismatch in major case.
- Cache issue
  You have cache plugin then disable it and try.If browser cache then use privet window.